# Update a sg to add port from existing sg using boto.authorize

Tags: boto

I am trying to update a security group to add a port from other security group.
Ex: `sg.authorize('tcp', 22, 22, sg-123456)`

But I am getting the below error

```
sg.authorize('sg-abcdef', 'tcp', 22, 22, 'sg-123456')

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/ec2/securitygroup.py", line 187, in authorize
    src_group_owner_id = src_group.owner_id
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'owner_id'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the `authorize` method of the `SecurityGroup` object you have to pass in another `SecurityGroup` object representing the source security group.  You appear to be passing in a string containing the ID of the security group.

You could also use the `authorize_security_group` method of the `EC2Connection` object.  That does accept a string value for the source security group:

```
ec2.authorize_security_group(group_id='sg-abcdef', ip_protocol='tcp', from_port=22, to_port=22, src_security_group_group_id='sg-123456', src_security_group_owner_id='123456789012')
```

Comment: I used authorize_security_group method for the ec2 conn object and it is working.. thank you :)